# True or not $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lvert\log\sqrt{f(x)}\rvert dx\le\frac12\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lvert\log\left(f(x)\right)\rvert dx$

Tags: integration, inequality, logarithms

> Is the following true ?
>
> $$\int\limits\lvert\log\sqrt{f(x)}\rvert dx\le\frac12\int\limits\lvert\log\left(f(x)\right)\rvert dx$$ when $f\ge0$ and is bounded ?

Is this a consequence of a Jensen-type inequality ?

Comment: $\log\sqrt{f(x)}={1\over 2}\log f(x)$.

Comment: Try f(x)=x  with x=0 , and negative x ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik "when $f\geq 0$ and is bounded"

Comment: I know , i just show to him that there is a missed condition

Comment: Did you mean $\log\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{f(x)}\, dx\right)\le\frac12\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lvert\log\left(f(x)\right)\rvert dx$ instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an equality: $\log x^{1/2}=\frac12\,\log x $. for $x>0$

Comment: but for x positive